# User-facing download of a file hosted on S3 bucket with lambda generated presigned url

Tags: javascript, html, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to have a website where the user inputs a certain string, and based on that string I return a matching file for the user to download. Currently I have it set up so that there is a lambda function that does the matching, and the webpage talks to the lambda function via API gateway. The result of the lambda function is a dynamically generated presigned URL which is valid for one hour.

So far I have code that downloads a file (FILENAME.json) which is one line and just contains the presigned URL (in quotes), which I would then have to open to get a link and then manually place it in my browser. Is there a way to modify this code to directly download the S3-hosted file? I've removed the exact link and replaced a part of it with ********.

```
fetch("https://********.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test", requestOptions)
.then((res) => { return res.blob(); })
.then((data) => {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
  a.download = "FILENAME";
  a.click();
})
```

Comment: So `data` contains just a URL in quotes right?  Did you try `fits.href = data;`?

Comment: actually I copied in the wrong version of the code (fixed now). if I swap to a.href = data, I get taken to a 
"Your file can't be accessed" page, with file:///Users/USERNAME/Desktop/FOLDER/webfiles/[object%20Blob] as the link

(the page isn't live yet, just testing locally)

Comment: So, does `data` contain the file you want to serve, or the url to it?  From the above code it looks like the file itself, but that doesn't make sense with what you said about getting the URL.

Comment: data has the S3 presigned URL link to the file, not the file download itself.

Comment: Can you please provide the content of the JSON

Comment: if I do:

`fetch("https://*****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test", requestOptions)
    .then((res) => { return res.blob();})
    .then((data) => {
      var fits = document.createElement("a");
      fits.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
      window.open(fits.href,"_blank");`

then it opens a new tab with the S3 presigned URL as plain text in quotes

Answer (score 0):

I was overcomplicating things. The following works just fine:

```
    response = fetch("https://******.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test", requestOptions)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => obj = data)
  .then(obj => window.open(obj, "_blank"))
}
```

Comment: Please mark this as solved to help other people who may come across this question. Read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask